# What might corrupt a winforms progressBar?

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework

A progressBar occasionally stops updating (along with the rest of the GUI) and is missing a rectangular section.
This has only been seen intermittently on the target windows-ce 5.0 tablet device, never on windows 7.
progressBar.Refresh() after changing progressBar.Maximum does not help.
The exact sequence to cause it is unknown and I am unable to run the debugger on the target device (I use the PC platform to debug the application, but this issue has never been seen when running the app on the PC). 
What might be causing this?
The progress bar and its associated Label are updated this way.

```
progressBar.Value = Status.value;
label.Text = Status.value;
```

label.Text is always correct.

Comment: Updating from background Thread without invoking?

Comment: I'm `using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to update the progressBar and all other GUI components.

Comment: the application is still interacting? Maybe resources consumption makes it hang? Try playing with threads priorities.

Comment: Have you tested this on multiple tablets? If it is the same tablet, you might have damaged pixels that can not display the info. A quick test would be to move your progress bar to a different portion of the screen and let it run again.

Comment: @LexRema: the application still runs. There are a number of other controls (and progress bars) still working properly.

Comment: @jp2code: Yes. I have seen this on multiple tablets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is making changes to the gui outside the gui thread. The actual solution was making all changes to the progress bar in a System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

Answer (score 1):

You could echo data to a Label control, particularly something like

```
debugLabel.Text = progressBar1.Value;
```

This would help you find what values of the progress bar are not showing up and if it is consistently the same values or random values.

Random values would make me think the GUI is too busy to break away.

Same values would make me think bad pixels on the device.

Do you have any more data to supply?

Comment: I just added a snippet showing how the progress bar and its associated Label are updated.

Comment: I'm guessing `Status.Value` is an `Integer` type. If it were a fractional value (`float`, `double`, etc.) you would be losing data on the cast down to `int`.

Comment: Yes. Status.Value is an Integer type.

Comment: It could be related to the Progress Bar issue on Win7 and WinForms. You can code a loop (0 to 99), stepping the Progress Bar each time, and the visible Progress Bar Value will lag behind the actual value that you set in code. On Win7, though, I think it is a time issue: The displayed Progress Bar Position seems to receive updates slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the UI thread isn't getting enough quantum to fully paint everything it needs to.  Try calling an `Application.DoEvents` after setting its value and the Label Text update.

Comment: Chris! I haven't heard from you since I used to post on the Microsoft boards using Outlook Express.